# Laravel: Auth::attemp - Why Authentication failed?

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-validation

I'm authenticating users with conditions i.e. if

> **User role = 1**  Login should be successful else login should fail

Now what I'm doing for now is:

```
if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'role' => 1)))
{
    // Login User
} else {
    return Redirect::route('admin.login')
        ->with('message', 'Unauthorized user Or wrong email / password combination');
}
```

It is working fine, but when authentication fails, I want to be able to figure out the reason why it failed so I will be able to display following messages based on the reason of failed authentication:

- non-existing email address
- wrong password
- incorrect user role.

Is there a way to do these things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @The Shift Exchange here is how I've figured it out:

```
if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'role' => 1)))
{
    dd('Login Successful');
} else {
    if( Auth::validate( array( 'email' => $email, 'password' => $password ) ) ) 
    {
        // Wrong Role
        dd('Unauthorized user');
    } else {
        dd('Wrong email / password');
    }
}
```

This worked!!

Answer (score 3):

The trick is to use `Auth::validate()` in the failed section. You'll have to do a couple of validates to work out which is the issue

```
if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'role' => 1)))
{
    // Login User
} else {
    Auth::validate(array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password)) {
           // Wrong role
 } else { 
    if (User::where('email', $email)->first()) {
           // Wrong password
    }  else {
       // Wrong username
    } 
}
```

Comment: Auth::validate(array('email' => $email)) { failed, maybe because Auth::validate requires two variables (email and password)

Comment: @Jazzbot - yeah - probably. In that case you could change it to something like `if (User::where('email', $email)->first())`

Comment: I've played around with it and have sorted out the issue. Added my answer on how I've fixed it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

try validation first then try to attempt login

```
  Validating Multiple Fields
```

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation

Answer (score 0):

I hope this might help

```
public function postSignIn() {
    // checking for  validation
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), array(
                'email'     => 'required|email',
                'password'  => 'required'

    ));
    //if validation fails
    if ($validator->fails()) {
            return Redirect::route('sign-In')
                            ->withErrors($validator)
                            ->withInput();
 } else {
        $auth = Auth::attempt(array(
                    'email' => Input::get('email'),
                    'password' => Input::get('password'),
                    'active' => 1,
                        ));

        if ($auth) {
                return Redirect::route('home');
       } else {
                return Redirect::route('sign-In')->with('fails', 'Email/password wrong, or account not activated.') ;
            }
```

on the view write these response validations on top or below every fields with field names where email is the field name

```
      @if($errors->has('email'))
        {{$errors->first('email')}}
      @endif


      @if($errors->has('password'))
        {{$errors->first('passwrd')}}
      @endif
```

Since I am new to laravel so I have been using the longer process

Comment: That doesnt tell you which field caused the Auth attempt to fail. Only if they are all present or not. i.e. if they put the wrong password - this is not displayed in your validation.

Comment: What you're doing is validating email and password based on validation rules, it has nothing to do with why Authentication has failed. Validator::make and Auth::validate are two different things

Comment: U r probably right but my validation is for just the basic understanding if u want to pull it to the next level then your one is the best

Answer (score 0):

this is the function laravel use for auth purpose.
if you see here : vendor/laravel/framework/src/illuminate/Auth/Guard.php

```
public function attempt(array $credentials = array(), $remember = false, $login = true)
{
    $this->fireAttemptEvent($credentials, $remember, $login);

    $this->lastAttempted = $user = $this->provider->retrieveByCredentials($credentials);

    // If an implementation of UserInterface was returned, we'll ask the provider
    // to validate the user against the given credentials, and if they are in
    // fact valid we'll log the users into the application and return true.
    if ($this->hasValidCredentials($user, $credentials))
    {
        if ($login) $this->login($user, $remember);

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

and if you see through source this function use hasValidCredentials function
and if you dig further the function is :

```
protected function hasValidCredentials($user, $credentials)
    {
        return ! is_null($user) &&     $this->provider->validateCredentials($user, $credentials);
    }
```

and in UserProviderInterface interface you see this interface has been defined and you can implement it your self and return reason of auth problem instead of false or true